# firestore update a map field

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I have the following code, and I want to replace the long ID with my variable but I am not sure how can I insert the variable in between.
I want it to be 'cursos.curso.calificaion': calificacion, were curso is the variable.
Thank you

```
examAttempt(user: any, curso: any, calificacion: any) {
this.afs.doc(`users/${user.id}`).update({
  'cursos.tkGXjZLxRdg1TcXGGCD0.calificaion': calificacion,
  'cursos.tkGXjZLxRdg1TcXGGCD0.intentos': 5
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is save the route of how to fin d on firebase in a string variable and just pasted the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can update object maps in firestore by wrapping the string in an index selector

```js
Attempt(user: any, curso: any, calificacion: any) { 
   this.afs.doc(users/${user.id})
      .update({ ['cursos.tkGXjZLxRdg1TcXGGCD0.calificaion']: calificacion, 
                 ['cursos.tkGXjZLxRdg1TcXGGCD0.intentos']: 5 }); 
}
```

Comment: I want to replace the id that I manually added between cusos.(id).calificacion with a variable, but I am not sure how can I place it there

Comment: you swap out the string with a string reference. `[myString]`